# Error when combining rollapply() and weighted.mean() in an lapply() data.table setting

Tags: r, data.table, rollapply

I ran the following code:

```
id <- c(67, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58)
ratio <- c(0.5421248, 0.1558647, 0.1314578, 0.1095102, 0.1149908, 0.1645262, 0.1431160, 0.1633623,
       1.1375268, 1.3219208, 1.3830684, 1.5942101, 0.5991420, 0.6303874)
DT <- data.table(id, ratio)

DT[, lapply(.SD, 
            function(x) rollapplyr(x, 
                                   width = 3,
                                   weighted.mean, 
                                   w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
                                   align = 'right', 
                                   fill = NA)),
   by = id,
   .SDcols = 'ratio']
```

And it gives the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , lapply(.SD, function(x) rollapplyr(x, width = 3,  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'double' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

When I exclude the first row like this:

```
DT[2:14, lapply(.SD, 
                function(x) rollapplyr(x, 
                                       width = 3,
                                       weighted.mean, 
                                       w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
                                       align = 'right', 
                                       fill = NA)),
       by = id,
       .SDcols = 'ratio']
```

I don't get an error. I suppose it has something to do with there being only one id = 67.

Is there a way to avoid this error and just get NA for id 67?

I don't really understand why it doesn't work because this works:

```
rollapplyr(ratio, 
           width = 3,
           weighted.mean, 
           w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
           align = 'right', 
           fill = NA)
```

Comment: The first group is type logical and the other groups are double (because there is only one value for `id = 67`. `data.table` lets you know that not all groups are the same type. Because it is solo, `NA` is not coerced and remains type logical unless specify a different constant. see `?NA` for more info. I believe you can fix it if you change the fill to `fill = NA_real_` so it will all be type double.

Comment: Also align="right" is redundant because the code is already using rollapplyr with an r on the end which means right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Andrew's comment:

```r
DT[, lapply(.SD, zoo::rollapplyr,
            width = 3, FUN = weighted.mean,
            w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5), fill = NA_real_),
   by = id, .SDcols = 'ratio']
#     id     ratio
#  1: 67        NA
#  2: 39        NA
#  3: 39        NA
#  4: 39 0.1253654
#  5: 39 0.1166400
#  6: 39 0.1386624
#  7: 39 0.1439140
#  8: 39 0.1575212
#  9: 58        NA
# 10: 58        NA
# 11: 58 1.3156158
# 12: 58 1.4764097
# 13: 58 1.0544477
# 14: 58 0.8137783
```

The two changes made here:

1. **`NA` to `NA_real_`**. Many functions enforce preserving the class on operations; in this case, `zoo::rollapplyr` has an input class of `numeric`, but `class(NA)` returns `logical`. This might be a good time to note that `NA` actually has at least seven variants: `NA` (logical), `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, `c.Date(NA)`, `c.POSIXlt(NA)`, and `c.POSIXct(NA)`. Several of them are documented in `?NA`, the others are found by exploration. (This preservation of class is also present in functions such as `dplyr::if_else` and `data.table::fifelse`, but sadly not with base's `ifelse`.)
2. Not a bug, granted, but **removal of `align="right"`**, since in this case it is redundant with the use of the `rollapplyr` function (the trailing `r` indicates "right").

Comment: (If @Andrew comes back to claim the answer, I'll delete this answer ... didn't want to leave it dangling. :-)

Comment: Also the `data.table` may be the one preserving type across groups. At least, that is how I understood the error message. From a quick look, I couldn't find any specific documentation though, and this seems like it may be easy enough to coerce if the group only contains `NA`'s. My hunch could definitely be wrong